# tkinter: same icon for every window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a main root window and I set an icon to an image but when I create a toplevel the icon is not the same which the root window has. So I have to set the icon for it as well. However I have a lot of toplevels and it is a pain to specify for each toplevel what the icon should be. Is there a shortcut to automaticall set the icon of a toplevel as soon as it is created?

```
root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap('img.ico')

top1 = toplevel(root)
top1.iconbitmap('img.ico')
top2 = toplevel(root)
top2.iconbitmap('img.ico')
top3 = toplevel(root)
top3.iconbitmap('img.ico')
# ...

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Define your own function that creates the new toplevel and sets it icon.

Comment: Isn't that the normal thing to do whenever you find yourself repeating the same code? Put it in a function.

Comment: your code won't run, when you wrote `toplevel` in the example is that supposed to be `Toplevel`, or is `toplevel` a function you've written somewhere?

Comment: Will a windows-only solution work for you, or do you need something that works cross-platform?

Comment: Use `root.iconphoto(True, ...)` which will then apply the same icon image to other `Toplevel` windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `root.iconphoto(True, ...)` (first argument set to True) to set the icon of the root window and then same icon will be used in subsequent created windows:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Root')

icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='trash.png')
root.iconphoto(True, icon)

top = tk.Toplevel()
top.title('Toplevel')

root.mainloop()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: That may well be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass `tk.Toplevel` to encapsulate the desired behavior, and pass it the proper icon:

Maybe like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TopIco(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, icon_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.iconbitmap(icon_path)

root = tk.Tk()
icon_path = 'im.ico'

root.iconbitmap('icon_path')
top1 = TopIco(root, icon_path)
top2 = TopIco(root, icon_path)
top3 = TopIco(root, icon_path)
# ...

root.mainloop()
```

You can add other common attributes of the `Toplevels` you need to your custom class `TopIco`

**[edit]** from @acw1668 in the comments (thanks):
`parent` is optional (implicit) for `tk.Toplevel`, but there are cases where the following will be needed instead:

```
class TopIco(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, icon_path):
        super().__init__(self, parent)
        self.iconbitmap(icon_path)
```

Comment: Should `.iconbitmap('icon_path')` be `.iconbitmap(icon_path)` instead? Also missing `parent` argument of `TopIco.__init__`: `def __init__(self, parent, icon_path)`.

Comment: Yes, good points @acw1668 - I edited the answer to include your important remarks.